# como validar uma quantidade de colunas de um arquivo csv em php?

Tags: php, csv

Estou fazendo *upload* com um `load data infile` no php. Nesse *upload* precisaria fazer uma validação da quantidade de colunas que tem o arquivo `.csv`. Se a quantidade for diferente da quantidade que vem do banco ele bloqueia o *load* para o banco.

Meu código esta abaixo:

```
//aqui é o caminho da pasta para onde o arquivo irá
$target_dir = "uploads/";

//aqui pega o arquivo no campo para fazer o upload
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
//pega a extensão
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$type = $_REQUEST["typeFile"];

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('Desculpe, seu arquivo não foi enviado');location.href='upload.php';</script>";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

    //echo $type."<br>";
    $arr = explode(".",$campo);
    $week = $arr[0];
    //echo $week;
    $block = substr($week,0,4); 
    echo $block;

 if($block == "WEEK" || $block == "week" || $block == "Week"){

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("erro1");
    $db = mysql_select_db("banco") or die("erro2");

    $delete = mysql_query("delete from reparo.producao where week = '$week'");

    $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/report/uploads/$campo'
                            INTO TABLE reparo.producao
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                            ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                            IGNORE 1 LINES
                            (@data_producao,@part_number,@total_producao,@week)
                            SET
                            `data_producao` = trim(@data_producao),
                            `part_number` = trim(@part_number),
                            `total_producao` = trim(@total_producao),
                            `week` = '$week'";

    mysql_query($sql)or die("erro3");   

}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Desculpe, renomeie o arquivo por exemplo week-5-16');location.href='upload.php';</script>";
}
        echo "<script>alert('enviado com sucesso!');location.href='upload.php';</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Desculpe, houve um erro ao enviar o arquivo');location.href='upload.php';</script>";
    }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar como fazer essa contagem de colunas do arquivo que irá fazer o *upload*?

Comment: o csv já vem com as colunas na primeira linha?

Comment: sim, mais não insiro no banco só gostaria de verificar a quantidade de colunas

Comment: Pegue essa linha, de um `explode()` e um `count()` para saber o número.

Comment: rray não entendi direito sua resposta, você fala para abrir o arquivo e fazer um explode da virgula

Comment: Isso mesmo, pode `fopen()` e ler apenas a primeira linha, imagino q seja ela q contenha o cabeçalho.

Answer (score -2):

Respondendo a sua pergunta "Alguém pode me ajudar como fazer essa contagem de colunas do arquivo que irá fazer o upload?"

Para fazer a contagem de colunas basta seguir o código abaixo:

```
// Informe o caminho do arquivo CSV. Se o arquivo não estiver na raiz indique o caminho conforme o seu projeto.

    $filePath = "meuarquivo.csv";

// Abre o arquivo CSV

    $fileCSV = fopen($filePath, 'r');

// Verifica todas as linhas do arquivo

    while (($lineFile = fgetcsv($fileCSV)) !== FALSE){
      $dataFile[] = $lineFile; // Armazena cada linha em uma matriz
    }

// Conta a quantidade de colunas do array na posição 0 

    $numColumns = count($dataFile[0]);

// Imprime a quantidade colunas. 

    echo $numColumns;

// Imprime o array para verificação dos dados.

    var_dump( $dataFile);
```

Agora com o valor desejado na variável `$numColumns` é só você fazer uma condicional `IF` conforme a sua necessidade.

Espero te ajudado!